# Move all files except some (file pattern) from a DOS command

Tags: batch-file, dos

From a DOS command I want to move all files that do not match a file name pattern.
Something like this:

For example I want to move all files that do not start with "aaa"

```
for %i in (*) do if not %i == aaa* move %i .\..
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**XCOPY** is designed to work with '*exclude*' lists... See below:

```
   dir /b /a-d "source"|findstr /b "aaa" >"%temp%\aaafiles.tmp"

   xcopy "source" "destination\" /exclude:%temp%\aaafiles.tmp /y
```

The first line performs a **DIR** (directory) listing of the *source* folder, listing files in bare format (**/b**) ignoring directory names (**/a-d**). The output is piped into the **FINDSTR** command.

**FINDSTR** looks at each filename and compares it's beginning (**/b**) with the string "*aaa*".

If the start of a filename matches the string "*aaa*", the filename is redirected (written) to the file *aaafiles.tmp* in the users **TEMP** directory.

The **/b** is vital because you don't want to exclude files such as *theaaafile.txt*.

The **XCOPY** command copies files from the *source* folder to the *destination* folder except files that are listed in *aaafiles.tmp*.

Prompting to overwrite existing files (**/y**) is turned off.

*source* and *destination* will need to be replaced your own foldernames.

Comment: It's a file copy though, not a move.  With large files, a copy can be extremely slow while a move on the same volume is nearly instantaneous.

Comment: Note: I found also option `/S` (display directory content recursively) useful.

Answer (score 7):

Robocopy is a possibility

```
robocopy source destination *.* /mov /XF aaa*.*
```

for options see here  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx

Answer (score 4):

One way you can do it is create a list of the files to move in a temporary file.  Then use the file in with the `for` command.  Generate the list using `findstr`.

```
> dir/b/a-d | findstr /v aaa* > "%temp%\@movelist"
> for /f %f in (%temp%\@movelist) do move %f ...
```

The first command gets a list of all files (with no directories) in the current directory and then pipes the list to `findstr` which excludes (`/v`) filenames that match the pattern and puts it in the file `@movelist` in the temp directory.  The second command just takes those results so you may do what you will with them (move it).

There's probably a better way to do it in a single command without the temporary file, I just don't know how to write it.  I'm not sure how to call the `dir` command from within the `for` command.  AFAIK it only takes program files that exist, not builtin commands.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind fiddling with the archive bit, you can use it to selectively copy and delete files based on a file mask.

Move (copy and delete) all files except those beginning w/"aaa" from current directory to "dest". May also specify full source path.

```
attrib +a *.*
attrib -a aaa*.*
xcopy /a [or /m] *.* dest
del /aa /q *.*
```

Answer (score 2):

In some cases it can be made more simple. For example, I had to copy recursively a bunch of directories but excluding all images (png and bmp files), so I simply created an `excludeList.txt` file containing:

```
.png
.bmp
```

and run

```
 xcopy /S /I <source> <dest> /exclude:c:\excludeList.txt
```

It will match any file or directory *containing* `.png`, but not necessarily *ending* by `.png`. (I did not investigate if smart use of wildcards or regular expressions are possible).
It does not handle your particular example (for which you have already a good answer) but it solved my problem, and this page is what I found when I googled in search of a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but moving all files to the destination and moving the files back to the source is a fast way with actual move operation (no copies). Of course this assumes there are no files in destination matching the wildcard.

`move source\*.* destination\ && move destination\aaa*.* source\`